# Help in shadow of cycles

Tags: graphics, circles

want to know how do I make the shadow of cycles

```
\usepackage[tikzpicture]
    \begin{document}[article
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale ,y=\imagescale]
    %posicione a imagem
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{C:/Users/Heisenberg/Desktop/PI/Frame0}};
    %aqui comeca o desenho
    %bolas
    \draw[fill=lime] (48.0097,40.0473) circle (1.3);
    \draw[fill=violet] (48.08,90.0252) circle (1.3);
    \draw [yellow,fill=yellow] (54.2657,32.875) circle (1.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}[article]
```

[image: gif animated]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm still not using animate package, ready already added the missing

Comment: This isn't a MWE. First, it's not compilable: no document class, `\begin{document}[article` has an unbalanced `[` character, and `\begin{document}` doesn't take parameters, etc. Second, `\imagescale` is undefined. There may be others. Make sure that any code you post is (a) compilable in its own document, (b) uses no external files (like your Frame0 image), and (c) is indented by 4 characters in your post (select the text in the post and press Ctrl-K).

Comment: Apart from the incomplete and uncompilable MWE, it is totally unclear to me what you are asking for. What do you mean with "shadow of cycles"?